# Different triggers for parallel stages in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to create a pipeline where there are multiple triggers for it - cron, pull request opened and manual. Hence, I wanted to visualize it accordingly.

This is my code with no triggers applied.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
        TRIGGER = 'PULL_REQUEST'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Trigger')
        {
            parallel{

                stage('Daily') {
                     when {
                          environment name: 'TRIGGER', value: 'DAILY' 
                     }
                     steps {
                           sh 'echo "daily build"'
                     }
                }
                stage('Pull Request') {
                     when {
                          environment name: 'TRIGGER', value: 'PULL_REQUEST' 
                     }
                     steps {
                           sh 'echo "pull request trigger"'
                     }
                }
                stage('Manual') {
                     when {
                          environment name: 'TRIGGER', value: 'MANUAL' 
                     }
                     steps {
                           sh 'echo "Manual"'
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "build step"'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "test step"'
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver for development') {
            when {
                environment name: 'CI', value: 'true' 
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "delivery for development"'
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                sh 'echo proceeded'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy for production') {
            when {
                environment name: 'CI', value: 'false'  
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo "deploy for production"'
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)'
                sh 'echo proceeded'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to achieve this with the above code : 
[image]

Now, my objective is to put the triggers in those parallel stages - Daily, Pull Request and Manual. However, I am not able to do so, as `trigger` is for the complete pipeline and perhaps expected to appear only once in the pipeline. How can I achieve this effect?

These 3 parallel triggers will set some environment variables which will be used in further stages to modify the pipeline flow accordingly, depending on the type of trigger.